# django rest framework token authentication and queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to filter using token authentication..

if remove get_queryset, get all TodoList author and working at postman.

but I want to filter user like get_queryset.

todo app in views.py

```
class TodoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = TodoSerializer
permission_classes = ()
#queryset = Todo.objects.all()


def get_queryset(self):
    return Todo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

and using Httpie, I get json I want!

```
(myvenv) D:\django\todo_project>http GET http://localhost:8000/todo/ "Authorization: Token 7681fc35d7fb9fdb20dbad65ca8220b3ca12c1e6"
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
[
    {
        "content": "todo!",
        "timestamp": "2018-07-11T10:06:27.710916Z",
        "title": "todo!",
        "updated": "2018-07-11T10:06:27.710916Z",
        "user": "user3"
    }
]
```

but using postman, error occurs..
[image: Postman get]

I think when filting, authentication is not working, so user is AnnoymouseUser

How can I filter request user???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `Token` word in Authorization value. It should be:

```
Authorization: Token <token_value>
```